# how use stimulsoft or crystalReport and profile provider asp.net4

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, report, provider

how use **stimulsoft-reports or crystalReport** and profile provider asp.net4(personalization)

Answer (score 2):

Add libraries to the project, put the components on a web form, set the properties (if necessary), load the report and assign it to the report viewer or a web designer
ASP.NET 2.0 and 4.0, no special differences other than .NET Framework.

Please read documentation of the product and a lot of examples of how to use ASP.NET in Stimulsoft Reports.Web are represented in the installation pack.